# How to display button on camera view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I creating an app that has two buttons, the first button is to open the video camera and the second button is to open a video from the gallery by using the image picker library. My question is it possible to display a button on video view or camera view just like in TikTok or Instagram.

Comment: yes its possible.check this post https://www.raywenderlich.com/4333657-using-the-camera-on-flutter

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented this was by using a stack, then having your camera view on the background and a **floating action button** in front. Example code:

```
Widget test() {
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    CameraPreview(),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 1, 1, 1), //margin here
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 2,
          onPressed: takePicture,
        )),
  ],
);
```

}

Comment: I am using this code "ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);" to open videocamera instead of using Camera Plugin